# Parallel processing with concurrent.futures

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing

I try to find a way to use different approaches for parallel processing on a dataframe like shown in this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKl2JW_qrso (min >18:26 ). But the results show me something went wrong. The idea of the code is to create a new column ['denominator'] in a dataframe with the rowsum of each field from the columns "basalareap","basalareas","basalaread". Any suggestion whats wrong here, that I‘m getting this weird results while print? Furthermore are there other ways to do parallelization most effective?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import concurrent.futures
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

np.random.seed(4)
layer = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,25,size=(10, 3)),
                  columns=list(['basalareap', 'basalareas', 'basalaread']))

def denom():
    layer['denominator'] = layer[["basalareap","basalareas","basalaread"]].sum(axis=1)

data_split = np.array_split(layer,cpu_count())


with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = [executor.submit(denom) for i in data_split]
print(results)

>>>print(results)
[<Future at 0x1b45e325108 state=finished raised BrokenProcessPool>, 
<Future at 0x1b45e357708 state=finished raised BrokenProcessPool>, 
<Future at 0x1b45e3577c8 state=finished raised BrokenProcessPool>, 
<Future at 0x1b45e357888 state=finished raised BrokenProcessPool>, 
<Future at 0x1b45e357948 state=finished raised BrokenProcessPool>, 
<Future at 0x1b45e357a48 state=finished raised BrokenProcessPool>, 
<Future at 0x1b45e357b08 state=finished raised BrokenProcessPool>, 
<Future at 0x1b45e357bc8 state=finished raised BrokenProcessPool>]
```

My system: Windows 10 python 3.7.4

Comment: _Any suggestion whats wrong here?_ Shouldn’t you be the one telling us what the issue is?

Comment: I clarified my question, but it should be obvious that I mean the output of the script „print(results)“

Comment: I had forgotten about this question! Is concurrency/parallelism a necessity here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way you can make it work (using your sample data):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import concurrent.futures as cf
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

np.random.seed(4)
layer = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,25,size=(10, 3)),
                  columns=list(['basalareap', 'basalareas', 'basalaread']))

def denom(layer):
    layer['denominator'] = layer[["basalareap","basalareas","basalaread"]].sum(axis=1)
    return layer

if __name__ == '__main__':

    data_split = np.array_split(layer,cpu_count())

    # create a function to for process tasks
    def cpu_tasks(func, *args):

        with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor() as tp:
            result = tp.map(func, chunksize=10, *args)
        return list(result)

    # get result
    newdf = cpu_tasks(denom, data_split)

    # convert list to dataframe
    newdf = pd.concat(newdf)
    print(newdf)


       basalareap  basalareas  basalaread  denominator
    0          14          23           5           42
    1           1           8          23           32
    2           8          18           9           35
    3           7          13          23           43
    4          23           8           4           35
    5          18          12           6           36
    6          10          20           3           33
    7           0          23          21           44
    8          21           9           6           36
    9           6          24           2           32
```